# Appengine not sending email

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use the Appengine Mail API to send mail from my application. I'm running the code below which executes fine without exceptions but no mail is actually sent. Here's the code:

```
public static void sendNotificationEmail(String subject, String message, String emailAddress) {
    System.err.println("Sending mail: " + emailAddress);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("a@b.com", "Name"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailAddress));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(message);
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.err.println("done");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

a@b.com is a registered owner of the app (but not the billing administrator). Looking at the logs, "done" is printed but no email is sent.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Found out the emails are actually getting through but are in the spam folder. Any way to give my app more (reputation) to not be marked as spam. Our app sends out notification emails to users when something has changed in the system.

Comment: Is it possible that it's in spam folder?

Comment: You found it! It is in the spam folder. Begs the question of how did I get marked as spam and how best to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you email marked as spam because it was sent from different host, I mean that maybe it's not GMail-connected domain.

At this case, to prevent it from being marked as spam, it's very helpful to configure [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) for your domain, see google help: [Creating an SPF record](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723). It has helped me some time ago